# Font Awesome icons not displaying correctly within footer

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <h1>This website is currently getting a makeover.</h1>
  <p>It will be back shortly with updated portofolio, revamped          (custom) design, and new pricing.</p>
  <footer>
    <p class="left copyright">Copyright &copy; 2016 Patrick Black</p>
    <a class="social right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

CSS (using preprocessor; Stylus; if want complete code please comment:

```
html {
  position relative
  min-height 100%
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align center
  height 100%
  margin 0 0 50px
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 30vh;
}
footer {
  background black
  color white
  height 50px
  position absolute
  bottom 0
  left 0
  width 100%
}
.left {
  text-align left
}
.right {
  float right
}
.copyright {
  margin-left 10px
}
.social {
  display inline-block
}
```

Here's the full code:: http://codepen.io/Mortiferr/pen/pyLYqa
As you can see, the Twitter icon is displaying below the footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
 <p class="left copyright">Copyright &copy; 2016 Patrick Black</p>
```

is full width of the page and so is forcing the twitter section to the next line.

You can fix this by floating that paragraph.

```
.left {
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EKLjpX)

Comment: Sweet. Now, it's not centered, how can I fix that.

Comment: That's a different question. Personally I wouldn't use floats here at all.

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this css for twitter font icon appropriate in footer.

```
.social {
 display inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 padding:6px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.copyright` rules:

```
display inline-block
float left
```

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 30vh;
}
footer {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.left {
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
}
.copyright {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.social {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="container">
  <h1>This website is currently getting a makeover.</h1>
  <p>It will be back shortly with updated portofolio, revamped (custom) design, and new pricing.</p>
  <footer>
    <p class="left copyright">Copyright &copy; 2016 Patrick Black</p>
    <a class="social right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
.left{
  float:left;
  text-align left;
}

i{
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNGOKy